# Make apache site hosted in a local computer accessible from outside

Tags: linux, apache-http-server

I have a working apache2 server hosting a Moodle site on LAN which can be accessed thru `http://192.x.x.x/moodle`. I also have a Linux server sitting between the Internet and the LAN with a live IP address `124.x.x.x`. I want to make the moodle site accessible from the Internet. Is it possible?

The local apache2 server has a working configuration to serve `moodle.domain.com`. The live Linux server also has an apache2 server hosting `domain.com`. Both are running Debian Linux

I tried to redirect `moodle.domain.com` to `192.x.x.x` from the live Linux server's `/etc/hosts` file but still, the `domain.com` is what I get when I access `moodle.domain.com` from the outside.

When I access from outside, I configure first the host file in a windows laptop to redirect `moodle.domain.com` to the live IP address of the Linux server.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

I got it working by implementing Apache reverse proxy in the live Linux Apache server.

For those who are looking for the same solution, here's a snippet of my `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName moodle.domain.com
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPass / http://10.5.1.100:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://10.5.1.100:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

The local Apache server hosting the actual Moodle site should be listening on port `8080`:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@local
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/moodle
    ServerName moodle.domain.com
    ServerAlias moodle.domain.com
    <Directory /srv/www/moodle>
           #Allowoverride all    ###Uncomment if required
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Another Moodle-specific setting I needed to tweak is the Moodle config file `/srv/www/moodle/config.php`:

> $CFG->wwwroot = 'http://moodle.domain.com';

Moodle initially set it to `$CFG->wwwroot = 'http://10.5.1.100/moodle';`during installation. If you have no Moodle installation, then ignore this part

Answer (score 1):

Before we start I want to make sure that you understand that it's not the safest option to do this way. Specially by opening router ports, so please make sure that you understand about firewall.

Since you have a dynamic IP (I'm presuming) you cannot simply bind it to your domain. This is because your IP will end up changing every couple hours.

This answer is based in most common router options available.

1. You must find your apache server in the router connections,
   and activate port forwarding (80) or, if you understand what you're
   doing and have a proper firewall initialized, you can simply open
   all router ports (I highly recommend you not doing this unless you
   have a firewall)
2. Use a free DNS service like Dyn DNS (most recent routers
   support this out of the box, just check the settings and setup an
   account).
3. Create a free DNS subdomain.
4. Create a DNS Rule (CNAME) from your main domain. and point it
   to your dyndns created subdomain. For example moodle.example.com ->
   trex-moodle.exampledyndns.com.
5. Configure your apache and add your dyndns subdomain.

Using a free dns in your router is the best option, since your router rotates the IP every couple hours, if you're using such a service, your dyn dns domain will be always pointing to your home IP address.

### Edit

Regarding the first comment, you'll need a nginx proxy running in your main linux server. The nginx can be used to host the  website `domain.com` and moodle.domain.com which is hosted in the different server in the same network.

Make sure that you can access the moodle website from your linux server. (Use ping IP)

Now in your nginx you'll need to have the following configuration:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name domain.com;

        root /your/domain.com/path/goes/here ;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  moodle.trex.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.X.X.X:80; #Your apache2 server local IP address
    }
}
```

For this to work, both Linux servers and your apache2 server must be under the same 192.X.X.X network.

Comment: I have a static live IP address. I also have a DNS entries in Hurricane Electric free DNS service so moodle.trex.com is actually resolving to the live IP of the Linux server. 
Performing port forwarding in the live Linux server successfully redirects HTTP requests to the local Moodle server. The problem is the Linux server also has its own Apache server hosting another website on port 80, thus being bypassed by the port forwarding. Is there a way to create an Apache VirtualHost in the live Linux server to pull contents from another VirtualHost from another machine?

Comment: Hello, thank you for specifying some details. Have you tried to make port forward using nginx? I'll update my answer in a bit

Comment: I did update the answer

Comment: I got it working using Apache reverse proxy. Thank you for your time

Comment: If your problem has been solved, please add your own answer with the steps you used, since it can be useful for others in the future ;)

Comment: I already did. Thanks once again